# Applying JavaScript to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, html-head

First and foremost, I apologize in advance for the ignorance on my part - I do not know JavaScript at all and I am somewhat new to Stackoverflow and jsFiddle. I did my homework and was able to get the functionality working on jsFiddle, but now (what should be the easy part) I cannot apply it to my HTML code. The working code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8p7J2/354/

Now that I have all the code I need (I'll add more styles later), how do I apply the JavaScript to the HTML?  I tried this with no success:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Walser Rewards - Contact Us</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Should it be in the header, right after/before the form, just before the /body tag, or somewhere else?

Comment: Script tags should be placed at the bottom of the HTML (unless otherwise necessary). What's not working? Is the path to your JS file correct?

Comment: This looks like it should work, provided `contact.js` is located in the same directory as the HTML.  What happens when you load the page?

Comment: Have a look at the source of the jsFiddle result frame and you will know.

Comment: Just in case you don't already, check out FireBug http://getfirebug.com/ while debugging.

Comment: @FelixKling - Thanks for making me feel stupid :p.  It works in FF and Safari, but not IE or Chrome: https://www.the-car-club.com/walsergold/contact.asp
Any ideas?

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK!  Not sure why this worked, but I had to take the "http:" out of the path so it just read "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" Thanks for the help everyone!!

Answer (score 4):

The source code in the working code (demo) uses the jQuery library so, you have to include that in your document. 
After `<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Add the line below.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

The point is, the script is loaded before HTML elements were rendered. If you have your code in `contact.js`, wrap it in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#member,").css("display","none");

    var showTop = $.cookie('showTop');
    if (showTop == 'expanded') {
      $("#member").show("fast");
      $('input[name=mbr]:checked');
    } else {
      $("#member").hide("fast");
      $('input[name=mbr]:checked');
  }
});

$(".mbr-yn").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=mbr]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
        $("#member").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        $.cookie('showTop', 'expanded'); //Add cookie 'ShowTop'
    }
    if ($('input[name=mbr]:checked').val() == "No"){ 
        $("#member").slideUp("fast");  
        $.cookie('showTop', 'collapsed'); //Add cookie 'ShowTop'
    }
 });
```

And don't forget to include jQuery library **before** your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, awesome job! There are a few small issues with what your doing that could be the cause. You actually have to make sure you include jQuery when using jQuery functionality. You can add this by including this line before you pull in your contacts.js file.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will set up $ to say that this is jQuery. Once you do that, you will have to make sure that it doesn't try and run your code until jQuery is fully loaded. to do that, put this at the begining of your contacts.js file.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

and then this at the bottom.

```
});
```

That wrapper just tells the page to not call your functions until everything has loaded properly. hope this helps! And never hesitate to ask questions :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Walser Rewards - Contact Us</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
put your jsfiddle javascript code here
</script>
</head>
<body>
put your jsfiddle html code here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not going to work as the OP requires the jquery library for their code to work.

Answer (score -1):

I would put it in an immediate function inside a script block just before the closing body tag so that it runs after the page content has loaded:

```
<script>

$(function() { 

/* in here */ 

}); 

</script>
```

Comment: The OP hasn't event included the jquery library in their html document, so this is not going to work.

Comment: Yes, but since the JavaScript OP wants to add to their document uses jQuery none of it is going to work with out a reference to it. This is still a valid response since they asked 'how do I apply the JavaScript to the HTML? ... Should it be in the header, right after/before the form, just before the /body tag, or somewhere else? 

Plus they also said '...I did my homework...' so I gave them some credit that they knew what jQuery is.